# Existance of an analytic function satisfying some condition

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exists an analytic function$f:D \to D$ ($D$ is the unit disc) such that

$f(\dfrac{i^{n}}{n})=-\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among others we have $f(\frac1{4n})=-\frac1{16n^2}$, which implies $f(z)=-z^2$ on a sequence with accumulation point in $D$, hence for all $z\in D$. But then $f(\frac i5)=\frac1{25}\ne -\frac1{25}$. Hence no such $f$ exists.